Intersect streets from ArcMap data in QGIS
I have a large data set of a base map for the city of Dresden. This was created in ArcMap and is available as an .mxd file. Unfortunately, .mxd data cannot be easily imported into QGIS, so I imported the data into QGIS using .lyr, exported the annotations as feature classes and then added them to QGIS using a GDB.
The individual streets are unfortunately not intersected, as in ArcMap, but overlap at the respective ends.
Is there a way to intersect them like in ArcMap?
For example, always intersect, when they overlap.
For a better overview, I have two pictures here. The 1st is the initial picture of how it should look. The 2nd image is the data set in QGIS, where roads overlap.
ArcGIS:

QGIS:


Perhaps a note of further clarification:
The roads are divided into sections in the respective layers, each section has its own row in the attribute table with start and end point. Hence this fragmentation in QGIS.
